# php api with port work offline only and not work online with curl and file get content

Tags: php, api, port

this is the api link
http://btakoss.com:8000/proc/search/s?nid=0501234567

it's work offline 
but online with curl or file_get_content not work

i test other site online and its work fine

this is my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://btakoss.com/proc/search/s?nid=0501234567");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64;rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100); // 5 seconds timeout
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
 {
     echo  curl_error($ch);
 }
curl_close ($ch);
```

also i use file_get_content() and not work
all this method work offline only

Comment: See if curl extension is installed in your php installation on the server.

Comment: thank you for your answer , i test other site and its work fine

Comment: What other site? Other server or other project? Does that project/server has anything to do with curl? Just check your current project with current server and make sure that curl is installed proprerly.

Comment: I tested your script and works fine. Looks like a problem with [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).

Comment: H.jbi i main curl work fine on server but not with my api

Comment: Thiago França you test the script offline ??

Comment: nope @AbdelhadyMohamed i used [php fiddle](http://main.xfiddle.com/836a20d4/curl.php)

Comment: @thiago-frança its not show the same when you view at browser

Comment: @AbdelhadyMohamed for me is the same, but not well formatted like in browser, open in your browser and press ctrl + u to see...

Comment: @thiago-frança in your link no data return at  {"t":[{"ID":"604850", .......

Comment: @AbdelhadyMohamed in my browser return no data at {"t":... too... In browser and phpfiddle I've exactly the same result...